# Using Solr for multiple sites

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, lucene, full-text-search, solrnet

I have setup a Solr server, now, I have two sites that I want to index and search using SolrNet.

How do I differentiate the two sites' content in Solr?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to take a look at this document: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/MultipleIndexes
I think the best approach is to use Multiple Solr Cores.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is you can simply add a new field that indicates the item's Web site.  For example, you can add a field called `type`.

Searches on website1.com would require you to filter on the `type` field.

```
&fq=type:website1.com
```

That way you only need to deal with one core and one schema.xml file. This works if the pages of both sites have a very similar field set, and it will make it easier to search across both sites if you plan on doing that.

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/MultipleIndexes#Flattening_Data_Into_a_Single_Index